# Excel how to add values in Column C if combination of values in column A and C is unique

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table listing rooms, type of windows and how much windows are in that room:
Example:

```
        COL-A| COL-B  | Col-C
Row1 |  Room | Window | Qty
Row2 |  A    | W1     | 1
Row3 |  A    | W2     | 1
Row4 |  A    | W1     | 1
Row5 |  B    | W1     | 1
Row6 |  B    | W1     | 1
Row7 |  B    | W1     | 1
Row8 |  B    | W1     | 1
...
```

I need to get a list telling how many Windows of each typ there is in each room:

```
       COL-A | COL-B  | Col-C
Row1 |  Room | Window | Qty
Row1 |  A    | W1     | 2
Row1 |  A    | W2     | 1
Row1 |  B    | W1     | 4
...
```

It means I have to add values in Column C (QTY) if the combination of values in Column A and B are the same.

I have tryed all sort of cformula combinations like `=SUMIFS(UNIQUE(A2:A100);AND;UNIQUE(B:100))` However without succes.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Best would be to handle this through a Pivot table in Excel to get the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just inserted a Pivot Table, and clicked on all fields to add to report, this is the screenshot of the result:

[image]

(The sigma values "Sum of Quantity is generated automatically, that's how basic this is)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need pivot table. You can also achieve it by formula. Try the following formula.

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:B8),y,SUMIFS(C2:C8,A2:A8,INDEX(x,,1),B2:B8,INDEX(x,,2)),HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]